# How do I make a Python Program demonstrating Zipf's Law?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

Zipf's law is a pattern found in many real-life affairs, a very common occurrence of Zipf's law is in passages of text, where the most commonly used word is twice in number of the second most common word.
I've been learning about dictionaries in Python and attempted to do this myself, and am confused about a few aspects of them.

The first step should first be to remove punctuation from the string (this is to prevent words like 'to,' or 'said-' in the next step), and then  `.split` into a list. Then, create a dictionary with the keys being the words and the values as their occurrences, this can be done using a `for` loop. Then, what I suspect might be the most difficult part would be to print all the keys and values in descending order.

If not the entire code, could you please tell me how I can do every step so I could do it myself? Thank you!

```
import operator, pprint

punctuater = ['`','~','!','@','#','$','%','*','(',')','-', \
              '_','+','=','[','\]','{','}','|','\\','\"','\'', \
              ':',';','<',',','>','.','/','?','^','&']
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

def convertForZipf(string):
    string = (string.lower())
    for i in punctuater:
        if i in string:
            string = string.replace(i, '')
    return string.split()

text = 'Lorem Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Meow h h h h h n n n n n dolor dolor'
words = convertForZipf(text)
wordsRanked = {}

for i in words:
    wordsRanked.setdefault(i, 0)
    wordsRanked[i] += 1
wordsRanked = (str((sorted(wordsRanked.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))))

for i in wordsRanked:
    try:
        int(i)
        wordsRanked = wordsRanked.replace(str(i), str(i)+'\n')    
    except ValueError:
        pass
print((wordsRanked.replace('[','')
                  .replace('(','')
                  .replace(')','')
                  .replace(']','')
                  .replace(',',' : ')))
```

I just need help with one last thing before I can officially finish this project, I'm having an issue with the display of the output, my code is highly inconsistent, and i'm open to suggestions.

Comment: For the "most difficult part" take a look at Counters https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter. One of my favorite Python features :)

Comment: `attempted to do this myself` - please show us the code you have so far!

Comment: @TomDalton I've added in the link, it's not the best code, but it (somewhat) works. I'd love to see your take on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fit your criteria - I'm not sure what you were doing with the for loop towards the end of your code - were you trying to replace numbers? If so, you could alter the regex pattern that I used.

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

pattern = re.compile('[\W_]+')

def convertForZipf(string):
    string = string.lower()
    pattern.sub('', string)
    return string.split()

text = 'Lorem Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Meow h h h h h n n n n n dolor dolor'
words = convertForZipf(text)
wordsRanked = {}

for i in words:
    if i not in wordsRanked:
        wordsRanked[i] = 1
    else:
        wordsRanked[i] += 1

wordsRanked = OrderedDict(sorted(wordsRanked.items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True))

for k, v in wordsRanked.items():
    print(f"{k} appears {v} times.")
```

Output:

```
h appears 5 times.
n appears 5 times.
ipsum appears 3 times.
dolor appears 2 times.
lorem appears 1 times.
meow appears 1 times.
```